# no contents showing after loading data in TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm new in javafx, I tried to follow some tutorials but I can't figure out what's the problem. I'm trying to load some data into a TableView but always it shows me a blank table although when I insert System.out.print for testing, it shows me that data was loaded successfully in the table.

Edited:

this is the Duration class:

```
package test;

import javafx.beans.property.*;

/**
 *
 * @author MohammedAli
 */
public class Duration {
    
    private SimpleIntegerProperty durationMonth;
    private SimpleDoubleProperty fee;
    
    public Duration(int d, double f) {
        this.durationMonth = new SimpleIntegerProperty(d);
        this.fee = new SimpleDoubleProperty(f);
    }
    
    public int getDurationMonth() {
        return durationMonth.get();
    }

    public void setDurationMonth(int duration_month) {
        this.durationMonth.set(duration_month);
    }
    
    public double getFee() {
        return fee.get();
    }

    public void setFee(double fee) {
        this.fee.set(fee);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Duration{" + "duration_month=" + durationMonth + ", fee=" + fee + '}';
    }
    
}
```

this is SetupDurationsView.fxml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="test.SetupDurationsViewController">
   <children>
        <VBox layoutX="67.0" layoutY="224.0" spacing="25.0">
           <children>
              <Button layoutX="67.0" layoutY="224.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addDuration" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="79.0" text="Add" textFill="#0707ff">
                 <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
                 </font>
              </Button>
           </children>
           <HBox.margin>
              <Insets left="45.0" />
           </HBox.margin>
        </VBox>
        <TableView fx:id="tableDuration" editable="true" fixedCellSize="1.0" layoutX="211.0" layoutY="214.0" prefHeight="230.0" prefWidth="323.0">
           <columns>
              <TableColumn fx:id="durationMonth" prefWidth="170.0" text="Duratin (months)" />
              <TableColumn fx:id="fee" prefWidth="151.0" text="Fee (BD)" />
           </columns>
        </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

here is the SetupDurationsViewController class:

```
package test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author MohammedAli
 */
public class SetupDurationsViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TableView<Duration> tableDuration;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Duration, Integer> durationMonth;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Duration, Double> fee;
    private final ObservableList data =  FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     * @param url
     * @param rb
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        tableDuration.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        durationMonth.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Duration, Integer>("durationMonth"));
        fee.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Duration, Double>("fee"));
        data.add(new Duration(1, 30));
        data.add(new Duration(3, 50));
        data.add(new Duration(6, 90));
        tableDuration.setItems(data);
    }    
    
    @FXML
    private void addDuration() {
        tableDuration.getItems().add(new Duration(2, 50));
        for(int i = 0; i < tableDuration.getItems().size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(tableDuration.getItems().get(i).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

and finally, this is the Main calss:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author MohammedAli
 */
public class Test extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SetupDurationsView.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Durations And Fees");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: don't see anything glaringly wrong .. so no way around a good round of debugging: a) to make sure the code you are providing here is the exact code that has the problem, change it to a [mcve] (you are nearly there: remove all unrelated ui - just the table and a single button to add data, add app boilerplate. imports and package statements (or put all in the same package). BTW: don't use static scope (though it will not make it to the revised example, because it's unrelated :), don't  use framework class names for custom classes

Comment: .. and don't use PropertyValueFactory: your data class exposes properties, use them :)

Comment: thanks @kleopatra, I updated my post with source code to make it as simple as possible, in addetion, i added the Main class where the program starting.  ** I didn't understand what you mean by not using PropertyValueFactory? and how to replace it?

Comment: I have this feeling that the problem is coming from the Main class where the fxml file loaded !

Comment: thanks for the good mcve, that's perfect :) Took me still a bit because everything looks just fine and is okay except .. a mis-configuration of the tableView in the fxml: fixedCellSize is set to 1, so the data/cells/rows are there but can't be seen because they are too small

Comment: have to run now, but as to alternatives to propertyValueFactory: there are many examples of how to use a property directly - assuming your data expose it in public api, it's something like setCellValueFactory(cc -> cc.getValue().durationMonthProperty)

Comment: To expand on not using `PropertyValueFactory`, the ideal replacement is to use a lambda expression. Something like `cdf -> cdf.getValue().someProperty()`. Doing it that way makes your code type safe (any errors, such as a missing property or misspelled property name, would be a compile-time error). The lambda expression also avoids the use of reflection.

Comment: @kleopatra set fxml: fixedCellSize to -1 and now working like a charm. That's why I love stack overflow. Thanks a lot.